# Can multiple Meteor Microservices be run in one galaxy container?

Tags: meteor, hosting, microservices

I'm developing microservices using Meteor and was wondering if there was a way to host multiple instances in one galaxy container?

Comment: Unlikely. You can have your app run on multiple containers but not the other way around. Galaxy should introduce a smaller pricing tier for real microservices as you can comfortably run a pretty decent app in less that 256MB.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @MichelFloyd, Galaxy is designed for scaling, not running multiple apps on one container - it might face some challenges in scaling all your things for you. So you might need to look at other ways.

If you use AWS or Digital Ocean (or any other similar hosting service), you can run multiple apps on the same box. You can either do this manually, or the excellent npm package `mup` makes it mostly easy for you. See http://meteor-up.com/

> EASILY DEPLOY YOUR APP
>
> Meteor Up is a production quality Meteor app deployment tool.
>
> Install with one command:
>
> $ npm install --global mup